# How write insert query with not exist from table

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in mysql and i need you help.

I have this value in my variable: `46,30,22`. I want to check this `46,30,22` is exist from save_user_id field. Exists number(value) not be inserted.

**My Current table: t5zgu_saved_user**

```
id  user_id  saved_user_id
350  42      46
354  42      30
353  42      70
351  42      288
330  57      66
334  57      67
324  57      59
```

I want result like this way:

```
id  user_id  saved_user_id
355  42      22
350  42      46
354  42      30
353  42      70
351  42      288
330  57      66
334  57      67
324  57      59
```

If you check in my result only one record added:

```
id  user_id  saved_user_id

355  42      22
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: see this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45277/mysql-insert-into-table-where-name-id-if-not-exist-then-insert-name-and-use

Answer (score 0):

### Query

```
INSERT INTO t5zgu_saved_user (user_id, saved_user_id)
SELECT {$user_id}, h.saved_user_id
FROM ({$str_union}) AS h
LEFT JOIN t5zgu_saved_user AS h2
ON h.saved_user_id = h2.saved_user_id
    # AND h2.user_id = {$user_id}
WHERE h2.id IS NULL
```

Whatever you're trying to do can probably also be done with `UNIQUE` keys and `INSERT IGNORE`. It will fail to insert duplicate values in that case. Uncomment the 2nd last line if you want it to have a unique `save_user_id` per `user_id`.

### Prework

Set `$user_id`

```
$arr_values = array(46, 30, 22);
$arr_union = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr_values); $i++)
    if ( ! $i)
        $arr_union[] = "SELECT {$arr_values[$i]} AS saved_user_id";
    else $arr_union[] = "SELECT {$arr_values[$i]}";

$str_union = implode(' UNION ', $arr_union);
```

For: `FROM (SELECT 46 AS saved_user_id UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 22) AS h`
To be: `FROM ({$str_union}) AS h`

### References

- [**`INSERT ... SELECT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)
- [**`UNION`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Comment: `SELECT 46 AS saved_user_id UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 22`: Could you kindly explain it a little? Thanks!

Comment: It creates a temporary table with 3 rows, the column name `saved_user_id` and the values 46, 30, 22. Consider it as using a dynamic and simplified table like any else.

Comment: Hey can explain me where to pass 46,30,22 this value from insert query. Thanks

Comment: I made a "Prework" section, where you see how I insert them into the query.

Comment: Okay let me check. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your Prework but i am little bit confused how to merge the code. :( Can you explain so i can implemente :)

Comment: You'd basicly only need to copy the query and define `$user_id` and `$str_union` before query is run. Plus having `$arr_values = array(46, 30, 22);` defined to relevant ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_change
BEFORE  INSERT  tablename
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
new_save_user_id number;
cursor c1 is select save_user_id from tablename 
BEGIN
for var in c1
loop
if (:new.save_user_id  NOT IN var.save_user_id)then
insert query
end loop; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

use save_user_id  field as primary key.otherwise you can check the existing data by code wheather the data(existing use save_user_id) is present or not.if present means block that data,else save into database. use various select query to get the value 
for example 
        
select saved_user_id from t5zgu_saved_user where saved_user_id = "Your Input";
it return if data already present with the Id,else it return null result.If you get null result means you enter that into DB else through exception.